# Do screenreaders ever access the content of an SVG?

Tags: svg, accessibility, screen-readers

The code I'm working on needs to pass the tests from Tenon.io, and it's flagging issues that occur within SVGs, specifically Test ID 75 (This 'id' is being used more than once). This is failing because the SVGs have identical ids for similar elements because they were generated by the same program (Illustrator I believe) and more than one appears on a page. I would think that any content inside an SVG would be irrelevant and shouldn't be flagged or even traversed by either a screenreader or Tenon.io's crawler.

I've tested the page where this issue appears in VoiceOver and it is ignored. Do other screenreaders do the same? Is there risk of any screenreader traversing an SVG DOM?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Screen readers can read an SVG as long as that screen reader has been coded to read a SVG.

SVGs have a number of accessibility tags which can be used and read by screen readers to describe what the SVG is representing or is meant to show.

The main accessibility tags are

- `<title>` which is used to title an SVG
- `<desc>` which is used to give a description of what the SVG is showing
- `<text>` which is text already on an SVG which the screen reader can access instead of using vectors to simulate characters

There are also normal properties you can use which screen readers use to help identify an object such as `role` to specify what the SVG is used for (like an `img`).

An alternative is just to create a fallback which is accessible to all screen readers as some do better than others at reading certain things.

Here are some good docs you can read up on which may be able to help:

- [SitePoint's SVG Accessibility Guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/)
- [CSS-Tricks SVG Accessibility Guide](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-svgs/)
- [W3C Doc on SVG Accessibility API Mappings](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-aam-1.0/)
- [W3C Accessibility Features of SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG-access/)

Comment: Do you know if JAWS and NVDA automatically read SVGs? Or is this more contingent on the SVG having elements catering to screenreaders?

Comment: I can see SVGs being readable being useful for a chart for instance, but not for decorative icons (which is what I have in this case). I use aria-hidden on the SVGs in question since they are also accompanied by a visually hidden span with a description, so I would assume the SVGs are ignorable.

Comment: @KatharineOsborne if you look just above this section https://css-tricks.com/accessible-svgs/#article-header-id-4 you'll see CSS-Tricks tried and tested on a number of screen readers

Comment: @KatharineOsborne and yes, accessibility I would say is much more useful for usable information than "this is an icon" or something along those lines. It can be useful for vector images by adding the description to give reason and understanding, much like adding an `alt` to a normal image.

Comment: @KatharineOsborne https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/12/using-aria-enhance-svg-accessibility/ this document also shows a full grid off browsers and screen readers and what they can use. This is 3 years out of date though so take it with a pinch of salt, especially since CSS-Tricks have tried on newer browsers and screenreaders with successful results.

Comment: @Stewardside thanks for the resources. The paciellogroup one is specific to the title and description elements, but doesn't answer the question of whether JAWS or NVDA traverse the rest of the SVG DOM (and again, this is specific to decorative SVGs that have no further information to add and just 'look pretty').

Comment: @KatharineOsborne sadly I can't help much more, I've never specifically worked with any screen readers, only coded according to the documentation and what is "supported" but have received no reports of problems. I think you'll have to do some testing yourself to find out if it works as expected for your use cases.

Comment: Post a URL and I can walk it in JAWS and NVDA. Regardless, Tenon should fail it as duplicate IDs are disallowed on a page, even in referenced elements like SVG. You may just want to manually edit the SVG files to prevent that (they are plain text after all).

Comment: If the svg has lots of garbage in it, perhaps a clean-up tool such as https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ will help you refine its attributes down to something intelligible